# how to insert image in style element of div

Tags: php, css, image, styles

I want to show `images/soldout.png` on my product cards when the `product_stock == 0`. I tried the code below but my `images/soldout.png` does not show on my card. What should i do to make it display on the card elements when the `product_stock == 0`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

This is my codes

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 form-group productidfocus" style="padding: 0 8px 0 8px;" >
    <div class="product-wrapper" id="productlist" style='<?php echo $product_stock == 0 ? "background-color:#d0d0d0;  background-image: url('images/soldout.png');" : "";  ?>'>
          <img class="product-img" loading="lazy" src="images/product-main/<?php echo $row['product_photo']; ?>" alt="">
          <div class="card-body" >
            <h5 class="product-title" style="min-height: 39px; text-decoration: none; width:150px; display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 2;-webkit-box-orient: vertical; overflow: hidden; text-align: left !important;"><?php echo $row['product_title']; ?></h5>
            <p class="product-price">RM<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>/KG</p>
               <p style="font-size: 10px; margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:-2px;" ><span class="text-danger" > <?php echo $sum = $row['totalquantity'] ?? 0;?> SOLD </span></p>
                <p style="font-size: 10px;" ><span class="text-success"><?php echo $row['product_stock']; ?> IN STOCK </span></p>
            <a href="product.php?cid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-block addtocart text-center" style="text-decoration: none">View More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add class on div tag when your product_stock ==0 otherwise not

```
You have to change path as per your requirements
```

**Add Single Image**

```
.card-body {
   background-image: url("https://soldout.png");
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

**Add Multiple Images**

```
.card-body {
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: 
       url("https://soldout.png"),
       url("https://soldout.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
   background-position: right, left; 
}
```